# how does lucene calculate intersection of documents so fast?

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

What are the internals of storage and search that allow this? As in the nitty gritties?

For example, I have a million documents matched by a term and a million others matched by a second term of an AND query. How does lucene do an intersection so fast in giving me top k?

Does it store the document in order of increasing doc IDS for every term? And then when two terms' documents have to be intersected, it looks for the first common k documents in both sets by iterating over them both incrementally, in a single pass.

Or, does it use simple unordered hash set from the larger documents array to find the common documents?

Or are both such(or possibly more) types of intersection polices used depending on the number of documents asked by user, those matched by individual terms etc among other factors?

Any articles which could point out the nitty gritty of document array merge will be appreciated.

Edit:
Thanks for the info guys. It makes sense now. Skip lists do the magic. I will dig more into it to gain clear understanding.

Comment: Lucene works with document numbers, not complete documents themselves, so any approach will work. I bet on using ordered document numbers for each term, but if you are really interested in _all_ details, it's worth to take a look at the source.

Comment: Great question and answers. I am surprised at how few votes are accumulated here, considering how many people are using Lucene/Solr for full-text and other non-text field searches.

Comment: Some queries also use data structured inspired by Roaring bitmaps to perform fast intersections and unions https://www.roaringbitmap.org/

Answer (score 5):

1. Indexes contains sorted documents. when you query with and operator(term1 AND term2) it use two iterators so when you know that first term1 starts with docN, you can skip all document for term2 till docN. So there are not only iterator with next method, but very efficient skipTo method. It is implemented with Skip list index(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).
   So by using method next and skipTo we iterate very fast over large chunks, and as data is sparse(those will not work for usual database for example) it very efficient.
2. Other point that lucene hold only N best so it is much faster than sort all scores document. If you request 10 best it is twice faster than if you request 20 best documents

Comment: point 1 makes sense. But am doubtful about point 2. The post shared by Xodarap talks differently. I will need to dive in deeper

Comment: I've got this information reading lucene source code and during writing my own Query implementations. I would recommend you to read BooleanScorer src(as Coady said) and related classes if you want to repeat my path.

Comment: @GuySensei: yura is pretty much right - if Lucene knows that a document will not be in the top N, it is ignored via some clever pruning algorithms. So it's not exactly that it holds only the top N, but it's not a bad simplification. (Note that the usefulness of this pruning will depend on your query - sometimes Lucene just has to look through everything.)

Answer (score 1):

Lucene will intersect sorted docs ids or use windows of bitsets, depending on the situation.  See the comments at the top of [BooleanScorer](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanScorer.java?view=markup).

Answer (score 1):

Intersection is similar to a [sort-merge join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join), except the IDs are already sorted. See [this blog post](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/09/lucene-performance.html) for more information.